# Isekaied in a late medieval world, how long before you get a flu and die?

Tags: medieval

You are in contact with 4 people a few minutes after your arrival and with an entire city after a day worth of traveling.

Can you reasonably expect to survive at least a month?

Comment: Uh, the guy will be vaccinated against the Flu. The people he’s in contact with have way more to fear.

Comment: @DTCooper does a vacine for the flu actually exist?

Comment: @DTCooper If he's vaccinated against the Flu, he'll be vaccinated against modern strains of different virusses. The yearly vaccination against the Flu is a different cocktail each year. It seems unlikely the most recent shot the hero got will protect him from the virusses that were around during the Middle Ages.

Comment: "Isekaied"? VTC for lack of detail.

Comment: @rek - "Isekai" is the Japanese name for the genre of stories where a modern-day person is transported to some other world and has some sort of adventure there.  "The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe" and the "Wizard of Oz" and their sequels would be Western examples of the genre. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isekai

Answer (score 3):

We are significantly more resistant to the typical viral and bacterial diseases of the historical periods, than those inhabitants themselves are.

For example, let's pick a ***nasty*** one. Yersina Pestis. Bubonic Plague, the dreaded Black Death.
To an average citizen of the mid 1300's that was exposed to this disease, the infection  rate was very nearly 100%, and the mortality rate of infected was 50%-60%.

To a modern person of european descent, the exact same disease has an infection rate of about 30%, and the mortality rate for *untreated* plague is about 35%.

Why the big difference?
Simple! We are descendants of those very few in the middle ages who GOT and SURVIVED bubonic plague, simply by luck of genetic makeup. The people that were more susceptible got the disease, and died without passing their genes on. Those that were less susceptible, or that managed greater resistance and thus better chance of survival, lived, had children, and passed these resistant genes on to their offspring.

I would be much more worried about the natives back in history. They might experience a dieoff as bad as the americas had, when europeans first went there.(up to 90%!!!)

Comment: The 90% was the result of several epidemic diseases.  It is likely our time traveler could carry one, but two is improbable.  (And the worst ones are improbable because of vaccination.)

Comment: If the resistance to a plague comes from a dominant gene, there is some chance that the protagonist might not be resistant. The gene loses its survival value once the plague is not around anymore and the protagonist might have two recessive copies.

Comment: The lower mortality rate is probably at least as likely to be from the evolution of the pathogen as from humans.  Remember that a microorganism does not "want" to kill its host, because then it has fewer opportunities to reproduce and spread.

Comment: @jamesqf Possibly, but why would a pathogen evolve to be easier on Europeans and south Asians, yet still be utterly lethal to Africans, and Pacific indigenes?

Comment: @PcMan: Because both things happen.  Evolution selects for humans with better resistance and microbes that are less pathogenic.

Answer (score 0):

Depends dose your world have the same bacteria and virus as are medieval world? If so your fine, probably immune to most deases from this time its everyone else that should be worried you should expect to start at least one plague if not more.